# sort list by lastname then first

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I am trying to sort a list generated by wordpress but a bit more custom.

```
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = " SUBSTRING_INDEX( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, ' ', -1 ) ASC"
```

In wordpress what this is doing is returning that sql statement into an sorting function.
This works to sort by the last word of the post title, (last name in my case) but if 2 people have the same last name I'd like it to then sort by first name as well.

So what I need is a sql line that will sort by last name and then First name.

Unfortunately it's all stored in the same column (post_title) and I can't change that.

I'm thinking I can somehow sort the column first by first name and then by last name but I am not able to figure it out.  Is there  a way to do this?

```
Jill Doodles
Brian Doodle
Billy Graham
Ryan Toon
Zedna Toon
James Zebra
Adam Zebra
David Zebra
Billy Zebra
```

But I would like it be sorted like this:

```
Brian Doodles
Jill Doodles
Billy Graham
Ryan Toon
Zedna Toon
Adam Zebra
Billy Zebra
David Zebra
James Zebra
```

PER @JoakimDanielson, I tried this:

```
 $orderby = " SUBSTR({$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, LOCATE(' ', {$wpdb->posts}.post_title) - 1), SUBSTR({$wpdb->posts}.post_title, LOCATE(' ', {$wpdb->posts}.post_title) + 1) ";
```

But it only sorted by first name.

- Adam Zebra
- Billy Graham
- Billy Zebra
- Brian Doodles
- david Zebra
- James Zebra
- Jill Doodles
- Ryan Toon
- Zedna Toon

but reversing his code to this made the world a better place:

```
$orderby = " SUBSTR({$wpdb->posts}.post_title, LOCATE(' ', {$wpdb->posts}.post_title) + 1) ASC, SUBSTR({$wpdb->posts}.post_title, 1, LOCATE(' ', {$wpdb->posts}.post_title) - 1) ASC ";
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff.  I added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one space, i.e one first name and one surname you can do like this

```
SELECT name
FROM table
ORDER BY SUBSTR(name, 1, LOCATE(' ', name) - 1),  
         SUBSTR(name, LOCATE(' ', name) + 1)
```

Above works with 5.6 of MySql but if you have v 8 and a more complex name string you can use regular expressions.

Comment: I'm not great at sql so I'm not sure i put it in right.  Can you check my update on my question.

Comment: Considering the circumstances, this is a pretty neat solution :)

Comment: This didn't work for me, but it pushed me in the right direction!!

Comment: @rudtek I now see that you wrote to sort on first name then on surname which my answer also does but your expected output is sorted by surname the first name. So switch the two substr if you want surname first

Comment: I didn't write that anywhere.  Are you saying to reverse your code lines?

Answer (score 1):

While @JoakimDanielson posted an answer that worked, this is the code that I ended up going with:

```
$orderby = " SUBSTRING_INDEX( {$wpdb->posts}.post_title, ' ', -1 ) ASC, {$wpdb->posts}.post_title ASC ";
```

Only in that it didn't need to `substr` functions.

I'm still posting his as the correct answer for leading me to the right place and I'm not totally sure one is better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

SQL's `ORDER BY` usually accepts a list of columns that is uses from left to right ... would something like `ORDER BY surname ASC, name ASC` work?

Comment: yeah, I only have one 1 column, so i need a way to do both on just that one.